# How to search within the node_modules folder in VS Code

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio-code

I am trying to find the JSON package file size and the disk space it is using in the node_modules folder. Where are those listed under?

Comment: You can use online tools like bundlephobia ( https://bundlephobia.com/ ) to determine the total size of your node_modules or single npm packages.

Answer (score 7):

In terms of the posible XY problem here, other answer and comments seem to answer the Y, but you seem to still want X. So:

I believe the default VS Code setting `search.exclude` includes `"**/node_modules": true,`. If you're really intent on being able to use VS Code's file-content searching facilities to search the contents of `node_modules` folders, you'll want to define `search.exclude` explicitly and remove that line from the auto-generated default config.

Note: The reason the default settings are like this is because most people don't usually/ever want to search the contents like that- at least by using VS Code. Including the contents of `node_modules` in searches can result in much more computational effort, and many more results that those users won't want to see. There may also be search indexing memory-costs. There are other good tools to do file-content searching in folders such as `git grep` (not really useful here, since most people don't check `node_modules` into version control), `grep`, and `ripgrep` (which actually VS Code's search feature uses under the hood).

Answer (score 7):

I found an easy way to do it, just open Node_modules in VScode as a new project, and search there.

Answer (score 4):

Here are the steps

**Step 1:** search your text from left sidebar, and you would be seeing "Open Setting" option there click on it

[image]

**Step 2:** then you see a list of excluded folders as below screenshot, just click cross icon for "**/node_modules"

[image]

That's it, search again now vs code will look inside node_modules as well

Answer (score 4):

By default, the `node_modules` folder is excluded. But you can temporarily change this for a search. Here's how:

Open the VS Code search (CTRL + SHIFT + F). Click the three dots ("...") just below the search box. Click on the wheel icon to the right of "Files to exclude". The background of the icon should now be grey.

The default exclusions are now **not** applied to the search, so the `node_modules` folder is included.

[image: button to click].

If you want to **only** search the node_modules folder, you can add `node_modules` to the files to include field. Or you can specify the search even further (e.g. search only in a single package folder).

[image: filtered results]]

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of plugins for `VS Code` that provide this functionality. Take a look at the marketplace https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vscode.
For instance, you could use this plugin https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xiaoluoboding.vscode-folder-size

Comment: I appreciate it! I was asked to look directly within node_modules though.

Comment: Unsure about the `node_modules` folder itself, but you could use this plugin to analyze your dependencies. I believe it would help you achieve the desired result: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=idered.npm

Answer (score -1):

Another way would to just include node_modules in search:

1. Press Ctrl + Shift + F, search sidebar opens
2. In "files to include" field, add "**/node_modules" (without double quotes)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfAUL.png)